# Transfer effect like Dojo modal window

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I know how to work with jQuery dialog, like below

### JQuery snippet

```
$("#PMinfo").dialog({

autoOpen: true,
height: 250,
width: 600,
modal: false,
draggable: false,
resizable: false,
close: function() {

var $this = $(this);

$this
    .dialog("widget")
    .effect("transfer", {

        to: "#smpb_info_btn",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer"

    }, 500, function() {

        $this.remove();

    });
```

}}

But I want to achieve the transfer effect like Dojo dialog. Here I am giving the link of page where user can go and see what kind of effect I want to achieve this effect with jquery dialog open and close. So please go to [the link page](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Dialog.html) and just click on view example button and see how the dialog appears with effect.

So I want that when user click on my button then dialog should open like Dojo with transfer effect and when close dialog then dialog should zoom out to button. Please guide me with code snippet that shows how I could get the same effect with jQuery dialog open and close.

**THE code i copy which is not working**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"    CodeFile="JQueryDialogWithTransferEffect.aspx.cs" Inherits="JQueryDialogWithTransferEffect" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<link href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"    type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>

 <style type="text/css">

.ui-effects-transfer 
{
 border: 2px dotted grey;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function ($) {
    // Set up the dialog, don't show it yet
    // Note the effects, they tie up with the
    // transfer effect we do later.



    $("#dialog").dialog({
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 1000
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        autoOpen: false
    });

    // Hook up the button to toggle showing/hiding
    // the dialog
    $("#btnToggle").click(function () {
        var dlg = $("#dialog");
        alert("pp");
        // Show or hide?
        if (dlg.is(":visible")) {
            // Hide: Kick off the transfer effect and close the
            // dialog. The transfer will run simultaneously
            // with the fade we configured above
            dlg.effect("transfer", {
                to: "#btnToggle",
                className: "ui-effects-transfer",
                duration: 500
            }).dialog("close");
        }
        else {
            // Show: Show the dialog, then kick off a transfer
            // effect transferring the button to the dialog's
            // widget. Again the transfer and fade run simultaneously
            // and so work together.
            dlg.dialog("open");
            $(this).effect("transfer", {
                to: dlg.dialog("widget"),
                className: "ui-effects-transfer"
            }, 500);
        }
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<input type="button" id="btnToggle" value="Toggle Dialog"/>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. 
The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

please just copy my code and run it in aspx file and see the result. please help me to get the error....what is wrong in my code. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify effects the dialog should use when appearing/disappearing in the dialog options:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  show: "slide",
  hide: "slide",
  autoOpen: false
});
```

[Live example using the "slide" effect](http://jsbin.com/amicev)

jQuery UI has a lot of effects available, you can find demos of them on [this examples page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/). One of them is bound to be roughly what you're looking for.

---

**Update**: The "transfer" effect, specifically, is a pain. :-) I finally got it mostly working, you'll want to tweak the durations and easings to tie up the parallel effects better:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btnToggle" value="Toggle Dialog">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog" style="display: none">
<p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-effects-transfer {
  border: 2px dotted grey;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // Set up the dialog, don't show it yet
  // Note the effects, they tie up with the
  // transfer effect we do later.
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    show: {
      effect:   "fade",
      duration: 1000
    },
    hide: {
      effect:   "fade",
      duration: 500
    },
    autoOpen: false
  });

  // Hook up the button to toggle showing/hiding
  // the dialog
  $("#btnToggle").click(function() {
    var dlg = $("#dialog");

    // Show or hide?
    if (dlg.is(":visible")) {
      // Hide: Kick off the transfer effect and close the
      // dialog. The transfer will run simultaneously
      // with the fade we configured above
      dlg.effect("transfer", {
        to: "#btnToggle",
        className: "ui-effects-transfer",
        duration: 500
      }).dialog("close");
    }
    else {
      // Show: Show the dialog, then kick off a transfer
      // effect transferring the button to the dialog's
      // widget. Again the transfer and fade run simultaneously
      // and so work together.
      dlg.dialog("open");
      $(this).effect("transfer", {
        to: dlg.dialog("widget"),
        className: "ui-effects-transfer"
      }, 500);
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/amicev/2)

For more on easings (which would help tie up the effects better), see the [easings showcase](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing).

Comment: when i use transfer effect this is not working. jQuery(function($) {
  // Set up the dialog, don't show it yet
  // Note the names of the effects
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    show: "transfer",
    hide: "transfer",
    autoOpen: false
  });

  // Hook up the button to toggle showing/hiding
  // the dialog
  $("#btnToggle").click(function() {
    var dlg = $("#dialog");
    if (dlg.is(":visible")) {
      dlg.dialog("close");
    }
    else {
      dlg.dialog("open");
    }
  });
}); just test it. can't we achieve dojo like dialog effect with jquery

Comment: @user750398: The transfer effect seems to be special, I've found some info on it and am looking at it. ("Just test it" is a tad bit aggressive, fyi.)

Comment: @user750398: Well that was fun. Finally got it mostly working. I'm really surprised jQuery UI doesn't have an option for this, as it's a fairly common UI thing these days...

Comment: please have look at my new code...why it is not working. what is missing.

Comment: @user750398: I'm guessing that the `<form id="form1" runat="server">` is an issue. Why do you have it set to run at the server? That doesn't make any sense... Also note that buttons don't have to be inside forms.

Comment: can i give any callback function name with transfer effect. actually i want show dialog when transfer effect completed. is there any way.

Comment: @user750398: **I** don't know of any, because you have to show the dialog in order for jQuery UI to determine its position on the page and such (unless you use a fixed position). But you can use easing to make it seem like the dialog shows up only near the end (having it fade in more slowly at the start). I'm afraid that's about all I can really help with, good luck with it.